# select last recent record - mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

table **payment** schema

```
installment | remaining balance | date
----------------------------------------
6,000       | 50,000            | 03 March 2017 5:30 PM
10,000      | 40,000            | 04 March 2017 7:00 AM
3,000       | 37,000            | 08 March 2017 3:00 PM
```

I want to select the last record which is this row

```
3,000       | 37,000            | 08 March 2017 3:00 PM
```

how can i achive that in mysql?

Comment: Read any beginners' book or tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM payment 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```